# Tokenize words and getting elements right before and after this word

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

My dataframe had a column of strings (col A). I tokenized it and now I have:

Input:

```
Col A
'A', B', 'C', 'dog', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C'
'A', B', 'B', 'dog', 'D', 'A', 'C', 'C', 'D'
```

I want to get 2 itens right before and after the word 'dog' in a column B. Therefore, I want something like this:

Output:

```
Col B
'B', 'C', 'dog', 'C', 'C'
'B', 'B', 'dog', 'D', 'A'
```

How do I get that?

Comment: Is the value a list of strings? It's not clear from your question...

Answer (score 0):

If there must exist one and only one `dog` in your column.

```py
import pandas as pd


df = pd.DataFrame({'Col A': ["'A', 'B', 'C', 'dog', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C'", "'A', 'B', 'B', 'dog', 'D', 'A', 'C', 'C', 'D'"]})

def extract(l):
    l = [e.strip() for e in l]
    idx = l.index("'dog'")
    return l[(idx-2 if idx-2 >= 0 else 0):idx+3]

df['Col B'] = df['Col A'].str.split(',').apply(extract)
```

```
print(df)

                                           Col A                        Col B
0       'A', 'B', 'C', 'dog', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C'  ['B', 'C', 'dog', 'C', 'C']
1  'A', 'B', 'B', 'dog', 'D', 'A', 'C', 'C', 'D'  ['B', 'B', 'dog', 'D', 'A']
```